# What happens if Android destroys my app's process and there was a Realm instance still open?

Tags: realm

If the OS destroys my app's process and there was a Realm instance still open, but no transactions executing, is there a chance that this will cause problems when my app starts back up again? If not, why not just open Realm instances in the application's custom `Application` class's `onCreate` method, store global references to them, and then just let the OS close them if/when it ends your app's process?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing inheriently wrong with that approach on the UI thread since it is a Looper thread that will auto-update the Realm, but remember that you need a Realm instance for each thread you want to work on.

Realm is an MVCC database, which means it can keep multiple versions of the data alive at the same time. This means that if you keep an Realm instance open on a non-looper thread, Realm will have to keep track of all changes between oldest and newest version. This can inflate the filesize.

In general we recommend controlling the life cycle as described in the below links. That will prevent any issues.

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#closing-realm-instances
https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances